# VC 2005 error "Il mismatch between 'P1' version '20060201' and 'P2' version '20050411'"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

I got one error I just can't find the problem, can someone help me or explain whats wrong? Still tried to comment out the problem or search just can't find any clues it just goes with this error:

```
 1>Compiling...
1>option.cpp
1>Linking...
1>fatal error C1900: Il mismatch between 'P1' version '20060201' and 'P2' version '20050411'
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1257: code generation failed
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\modestas\Desktop\ybtx\code\game\gas\GameGas\Release\BuildLog.htm"
1>GameGas - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 12 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

There is no code because can't understand where this occur happened.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to your question titles. Accept the answer that helped you the most. Also don't replace one question with a radically different one, ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 2):

It means, you defined `InitVariantContainer` declaration in the class, but you didn't implement its body:

```
void CCypherVariantHolderForDecode::InitVariantContainer(void)
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: i implement its body. Now i got 2 errors 1 is old one and 1 is new one.

Comment: Now, show the new error in your question.

Comment: I was commented out from include the 
void CCypherVariantHolderForDecode::InitVariantContainer(void)
{
  // ...
}
 part, now fixed but the same error i just don't get it...

Comment: Fixed, got new error.